# Free Shipping on a quantity of 25 or more for a single item

Tags: free-shipping

I am trying to set up free shipping on 3 items if the order is 25 or more.  I don't want to apply to all items just the three I have chosen

Comment: you want to add condition for order items is least  3 and grand total is 25 or more right?

Comment: One of the products I sell is books. I want to allow anyone ordering 25 or more books free shipping but anyone ordering 24 or less to pay shipping on the books